# Import Pcaml grammar to extend OCaml's printer using camlp5

Tags: parsing, ocaml

I want to create a printer extension for OCaml using **camlp5**. My code would look like the example of [this tutorial](https://camlp5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/printers.html) but instead of creating my own extension of the grammar, I would like to use OCaml's grammar to parse a program.

For that, I would like to use the **Pcaml** module to parse the given string with OCaml's grammar. Unfortunately, each time I try to use it, I get the:

`Required module 'Pcaml' is unavailable`

This is the part of my code where I load and open modules, as well as part of the code that uses Pcaml:

```
#load "pa_extprint.cmo";;
#load "q_MLast.cmo";;
#load "pa_o.cmo";;

open Pcaml;;
open Pprintf;;

let pa_ocaml = Grammar.Entry.create Pcaml.gram "pcaml_gram";;
```

I tried multiple command to run the program, like for example:

`ocamlc -pp camlp5o -I +camlp5 gramlib.cma <my_file>.ml`

What do I need to be able to use Pcaml and Pcaml.gram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use `ocamlfind` to build and link your programs. The only reason for newcomer against it, is that thing could become buggy when you use Windows without WSL. The compilation command without error is below

```
ocamlfind c -syntax camlp5o -package camlp5 -linkpkg a.ml
```

```
#load "pa_extprint.cmo";;
#load "q_MLast.cmo";;
#load "pa_o.cmo";;

open Pcaml;;
open Pprintf;;

let pa_ocaml : int Grammar.Entry.e = Grammar.Entry.create Pcaml.gram "pcaml_gram";;
```

FYI, your `#load` commands can and should be replaced by specifying right `ocamlfind`'s packages.